# Gridview loses its viewstate

Tags: gridview, viewstate

In a page, i put a gridview with several template field columns. In one of the template field, i have a linkbutton. Before postback i bind the grid with data. Once page loads, when i click the linkbutton in gridview, it is not firing the related event and its return a empty aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not checking for a PostBack before running a DataBind(). If you continually bind your data, ViewState will be recreated each time and you'll lose what you had.

Comment: Hi Joel, 
    Below is my code to bind the data to grid,
   
  if(!IsPostBack)
 {
     grdData.DataSource = GetEmployeeList();
     grdData.DataBind();
 }

Comment: What is the related event you're binding the linkbutton to? Are you using the RowCommand event?